# How do I make a header for whole document?

Tags: header-footer

I was looking for this topic. How could I solve it?

I have an issue with the code, when I define the header:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\title{\textbf{TITLE}}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
    \markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{
    \markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{Opt}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents

\section{RESUMEN EJECUTIVO}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*]
\item Los Par\'asitos
\item Cuantificar
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `fancyhdr`.

Comment: Please, give some more information. What class are you using? What form should this header have?

Comment: I got an error. This is the code. Is there something wrong?

Comment: The in the `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{Opt}`, the last argument should be `0pt` (a zero), instead of an uppercase `O`. Also, if you are writting in spanish, you may want to use the `inputenc` package: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, so you can write "parásitos" directly.

Comment: @guillem Good point, I mean for spanish writing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{Opt}
}
```

you have an "O" (the vowel) instead of a zero; here's your code with the corrected zero and some other modifications (I increased `\headheight` conveniently and instead of loading `color` and `colortbl`, you can load `xcolor` with the `table` option) and suppressed some information that was not relevant to the header issue:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
    \markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{
    \markright{\thesection\ #1}}

\begin{document}

\section{RESUMEN EJECUTIVO}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*]
\item Los Par\'asitos
\item Cuantificar
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Note that without a `\chapter` before `\section` you'll get an odd numbering.

Comment: Thanks, I also got it with: `\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \headheight=10pt

    \fancyhf{}

    \lhead{TITLE}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}` But I have another question: I want a small font for the header.

Comment: @Isai use an appropriate font size switch; for example: `\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\footnotesize\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\footnotesize\rightmark} \fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\footnotesize\leftmark}
`

Comment: I use this code, in the preamble:  `\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}  
 \lhead{}%It means, blank  
 \chead{}%Blank  
 \rhead{\footnotesize{TITLE\\  
 \textbf{Title}}}
 \lfoot{}
 \cfoot{}
 \rfoot{\thepage}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
 ` Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Isai You're welcome! I'm glad I could help. By the way, `\fotnotesize` does not receive arguments, so you could use `\rhead{\footnotesize TITLE\\ \textbf{Title}}`.